# Step ExecutionContext not promoted using Spring Cloud Task on Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes

I successfully deployed a remote partitioned job using Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Cloud Task; the installation is based on Kubernetes, so I added the Kubernetes implementation of Spring Cloud Deployer to the project.

But it seems that it's impossible to propagate values from the step execution context of a worker to the job execution context.

The worker tasklet writes some data into the step execution context, which is successfully saved in the "BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT" table:

```
@Bean   
public Tasklet workerTasklet() {

        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                ExecutionContext executionContext  = chunkContext.getStepContext()
                           .getStepExecution()
                           .getExecutionContext();
                
                Integer partitionNumber = executionContext.getInt("partitionNumber");
                
                System.out.println("This tasklet ran partition UPD1: " + partitionNumber);

                executionContext.put(RESULT_PREFIX+partitionNumber, "myResult "+partitionNumber);
                
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }
```

[image: batch_step_execution_context table]

There's an **ExecutionPromotionListener** which is added during the Step building process:

```
@Bean
public StepExecutionListener promotionListener() {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new
                        ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        
        listener.setKeys(new String[] {"result0","result1","result2","result3"});
        return listener;
}
@Bean
public Step workerStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
        .tasklet(workerTasklet())
        .listener(promotionListener())
        .build();
}
```

The job successfully completes and the work is partitioned properly and executed by 4 Kubernetes pods:

[image: rancher screenshot]

[image: Steps list]

But the expected values are not present in the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table.

Conversley, the step execution context propagation works with a partitioned job in a not cloud environment, for example using  a **TaskExecutorPartitionHandler**.

Comment: I _think_ what is happening is that any distributed partitioned job will have this issue. Have you tried with the `MessageChannelPartitionHandler`? My bet is that the same issue will arise.

Comment: Is your issue the same as (or similar to) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/924?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yes, it is exactly the same use case

Comment: ok thank you for your confirmation. Please add a comment on that issue with a reference to this SO question and we will take it from there. Contributions are welcome!

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/924#issuecomment-767430678